# Zoom a large image in IKImageView

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, ikimageview

I have an IKImageView in NSScrollView.
Now, I have two problems:

1. When I show a large image and zoom it, the animation loos very crappy. Is there a way to get it to switch images more smoothly?
2. When the image is zoomed bigger then the IKImageView, zoom - centerPoint lock on left - bottom of IKImageView. How can I set the zoom - centerPoint?

Thanks

f91kdash

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I need to do the same, and am also having some problems. Perhaps you wouldn't mind answering your own question? ;)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?